# memory allocation inside function by pointer to pointer

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I need to remove all references from my C++ code, and becuase my knowledge from pure C is quite old, thats why I would like to ask you for opinion.
Do you have any doubts with memory allocation in such way?:

```
void myallocator2(int** mystr, int* howmany)
{
    *howmany = 40;
    *mystr = (int*)malloc( (*howmany) * sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<*howmany;++i)
        (*mystr)[i] = i*2;
}

  int** mystr;
  int* howmany = new int();
  *howmany = 0;
  myallocator2(mystr,howmany);
  for(int i=0;i<*howmany;++i)
      do something (*mystr)[i]
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove all references?  Also why do you pass in a pointer to `howmany` but then set it to an arbitrary number?  I'm presuming you really just want to pass in an int, not a pointer to an int.

Comment: in C you don't have references, and code must be 100% C compatible. Variable "howmany" could be returned by function, but I want to save as much as possible from old code. Orginal method was:
void myallocator2(A*& mystr, int& howmany)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the C++ version of your code. No pesky dynamic allocation.

```
class A
{
public:
    int a_;
};

void myallocator2(std::vector<A>& mystr, int& howmany)
{
    howmany = 40;
    mystr.clear();
    mystr.reserve(howmany);
    for(int i=0;i<howmany;++i)
        mystr[i].a_ = i*2;
}

std::vector<A> mystr;
int howmany = 0;
myallocator2(mystr,howmany);
for(int i=0;i<howmany;++i)
    do something mystr[i].a_;
```

Disclaimer - yes, I chose to ignore "I need to remove all references from my C++ code". Unless you give us some clear, well-thought motivation, it's just a dumb requirement.

Comment: I don't need a C++ version, this code must be pure C

Comment: @zuko why did you tag it C++ then?

Comment: @zuko also, you do know there's no `new` in C, right? nor `class`.

Comment: my bad, C++ tag has been removed,
yes, I know, it is just a concept. Class can be replaced by char, or int basic types. The point of my question was: Can I allocate in safe way memory inside function in C like above (malloc can be used as well). [Please note that code in question has been changed - to avoid any missleadings]

Comment: @zuko what does safe mean in this context?

Comment: Does every C compiler can handle with such method of memory allocation?, and pointer *mystr set inside function will always have the same value after leaving myallocator2 function?

Comment: @zuko yes to the first question. Of course not to the second. How can it guarantee it will point to the same address every time?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go a secure way, use shared pointers